# jQuery horizontal and vertical slider

Tags: jquery, slider

Hy,

I'm searching for horizontal AND vertical jQuery slider and I can't find anything :(
I would like to have for example 4 slides horizontally and the second slide would have another vertical one.

Does anybody know such a slider?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Horizontal Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) and [Vertical Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range-vertical), just combine the two

Answer (score 0):

have a look there : http://jqueryui.com/slider/#multiple-vertical

I hope it works.

something like :

```
$( ".sliders" ).each(function() {
      // read initial values from markup and remove that
      var value = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 10 );
      $( this ).empty().slider({
        value: value,
        range: "min",
        animate: true,
        orientation: "vertical"
      });
    });
  });
```